# convert lines to fixed column length

Tags: formatting, textfiles

I would like to simply take a given text file and enforce a maximum column length of say 80. How can I turn this:

```
Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.
```

and turn it into this:

```
Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, a n
ew nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men 
are created equal.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the fold command:

```
fold -s -w 80 filename
```

Omit the `-s` option if you prefer to break at character boundaries rather than word boundaries (actually spaces).

I suspect this won't work very well if the text is encoded in a multibyte encoding such as UTF-8 (and contains non-ASCII characters).

If you are using Windows, use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) or [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) - they probably include fold.

Comment: Might want to do `fold -s -w 80 filename`, so that it breaks at spaces instead of the middle of the word.

Comment: @Hyppy: Thanks - I'll update the answer to include the -s option. @Gareth: thanks for adding the hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ fmt --width=80 <<< 'Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.'
Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent,
a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that
all men are created equal.
```